# How to match 2 urls with one regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a regex pattern to match 2 urls? The code I currently have matches the 1st url, but how would I make one pattern to match both urls. I am trying to obtain the random characters at the very end of each url.

http://www.videozer.com/video/yKKd

http://www.videozer.com/watch_video.php?v=rbgsd

```
preg_match('/http\:\/\/((www\.)?)videozer\.com\/video\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $URL, $result);
```

Comment: I would make a separate pattern, check them both and get on with my life.

Comment: There have been quite a few URL regex questions already asked here, are you sure none of them worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('@http://(?:www\.)?videozer\.com/(?:video/|watch_video\.php\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@', $URL, $result);
```

1. Use `(abc|def)` to match either the string 'abc' or 'def'
2. Use a different delimiter so you don't have to escape `/`

Comment: can you help me with this one also `@http://(?:www\.)(.*?)\.(?:com|net|es)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/@` I want the domain name and the name of the path after the com, net, es prefix

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
preg_match('/http\:\/\/((www\.)?)videozer\.com\/(video\/|watch_video\.php\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $URL, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just use matching groups. [You can see the result here](http://regexr.com?2v3ot).

```
preg_match('/http\:\/\/((www\.)?)videozer\.com\/(video\/|watch_video\.php\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $URL, $result);
```